# Google Sheets: Delete row 2 if row 23 gets a message

Tags: forms, google-sheets, delete-row

I have a Google Sheet connected to a Google Form which collects users' answers. I would like to remove row 2 of the spreadsheet when a message arrives to row 23, meaning that there should not be more than 22 rows in use. This way, I can read the messages in a mobile application.

I don't have a clue about programming, so if you can help me I would really appreciate it! :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the script is simple enough, but besides that it needs to be inserted into the project - you still need to configure the onFormSubmit trigger, which will run this script every time you Form Submit

```
function deleteSecRow() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1'),
      totalRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  if (totalRows>22) sheet.deleteRow(2);
}
```

where `Sheet1` - the name of the sheet where the answers from the Google Form go, but if you write *'I don't have a clue about programming'* then it must be hard for you to do

there are two ways to solve your problem:

1. you can share your table - and then somebody can insert the script and configure the trigger directly in your table
2. you can solve this problem without a script. On a new sheet in your table you make a query, which outputs only the last 22 rows from the first sheet. You can read the messages in a mobile application from this sheet

`=SORT(QUERY(Sheet1!A:Z, "order by A desc limit 22"),1,1)`

where `Sheet1!A:Z` - the range of the sheet where the answers from the Google Form go

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code @Sergey! What I did is triggering the function manually instead of doing it programatically, but it's fine because it works!